# Oracle view - sum to variable

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

How can i shorten the following select statement?

```
create or replace view V_AMV_PLG_QUOTES_50_MS as 
select 
    sum(NVL(ASK_SIZE,0))    as ASK_VOLUME, 

CASE WHEN 
          sum(CASE WHEN NVL(ASK_SIZE,0)=0 THEN CASE WHEN BASE_CURR_ASK_PRICE=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ELSE ASK_SIZE END)=0 THEN 1 
     ELSE sum(CASE WHEN NVL(ASK_SIZE,0)=0 THEN CASE WHEN BASE_CURR_ASK_PRICE=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ELSE ASK_SIZE END) END     as ASK_PRICE,


    EXCHANGE_SK         as EXCHANGE_SK, 
    PRODUCT_SK          as PRODUCT_SK, 
    BUSINESS_DATE       as BUSINESS_DATE 
from 
    S_AMV_PLG_QUOTE_AGG quotes 
where NVL(BASE_CURR_ASK_PRICE ,0) > 0
group by 
    EXCHANGE_SK, 
    PRODUCT_SK, 
    BUSINESS_DATE
```

Notice the very long calculation appears twice.. Can i insert it into a variable somehow? And just use the CASE operator on the Variable? (Notice we have a sum function there..)

Comment: Notice I want to sum all this long thing, And if the sum equals 0 i want to use 1, otherwise use the result of the sum..

Comment: you should be able to use a DECODE for that kind of logic.  are you worried about performance or code maintenance or what?

Comment: Code maintenance.. Looks awefull the original sum query is much longer i removed the most of it...

Comment: Note that sum(NVL(ASK_SIZE,0)) is better expressed as Coalesce(Sum(ask_size),0)

Comment: Also, "NVL(BASE_CURR_ASK_PRICE ,0) > 0" is the same as "BASE_CURR_ASK_PRICE > 0"

Comment: Thanks ! Yeah i noticed that later on, That a comparison between NULL and 0 is legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use create and use a variable within a view. If you just want to avoid repeating the nested case statement, you could move it (and the NVL) into an in-line view:

```
select 
    sum(MY_ASK_SIZE)    as ASK_VOLUME, 
    CASE WHEN sum(MY_ASK_PRICE)=0 THEN 1 
        ELSE sum(MY_ASK_PRICE)
        END             as ASK_PRICE,
    EXCHANGE_SK         as EXCHANGE_SK, 
    PRODUCT_SK          as PRODUCT_SK, 
    BUSINESS_DATE       as BUSINESS_DATE 
from (
    select
        EXCHANGE_SK, PRODUCT_SK, BUSINESS_DATE,
        NVL(ASK_SIZE,0) as MY_ASK_SIZE,
        CASE WHEN NVL(ASK_SIZE,0)=0 THEN
                CASE WHEN BASE_CURR_ASK_PRICE=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            ELSE ASK_SIZE
            END AS MY_ASK_PRICE
    from  S_AMV_PLG_QUOTE_AGG quotes 
    where NVL(BASE_CURR_ASK_PRICE ,0) > 0
)
group by 
    EXCHANGE_SK, 
    PRODUCT_SK, 
    BUSINESS_DATE;
```

The NVL and case are performed once, and aliased as MY_ASK_SIZE and MY_ASK_PRICE respectively; and those aliases are then used in the outer query, including within the sum.

If you want to avoid repeating the SUM too, move that into the in-line view as well, along with the group-by clause:

```
select 
    ASK_VOLUME          as ASK_VOLUME, 
    CASE WHEN ASK_PRICE=0 THEN 1
        ELSE ASK_PRICE
        END             as ASK_PRICE,
    EXCHANGE_SK         as EXCHANGE_SK, 
    PRODUCT_SK          as PRODUCT_SK, 
    BUSINESS_DATE       as BUSINESS_DATE 
from (
    select
        EXCHANGE_SK, PRODUCT_SK, BUSINESS_DATE,
        SUM(NVL(ASK_SIZE,0)) as ASK_VOLUME,
        SUM(CASE WHEN NVL(ASK_SIZE,0)=0 THEN
                CASE WHEN BASE_CURR_ASK_PRICE=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            ELSE ASK_SIZE
            END) AS ASK_PRICE
    from  S_AMV_PLG_QUOTE_AGG quotes 
    where NVL(BASE_CURR_ASK_PRICE ,0) > 0
    group by 
        EXCHANGE_SK, 
        PRODUCT_SK, 
        BUSINESS_DATE
);
```

Most of your column aliases are redundant but I've stuck with your pattern.

This is largely cosmetic though; Oracle's optimiser is likely to be clever enough to only perform the actual calculation once anyway, so I wouldn't expect to see much (or any) performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

I used creation of a simple ifZeroReturnOne function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ifZeroReturnOne (expr IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS retval NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT CASE WHEN expr=0 THEN 1
ELSE expr END
INTO retval
FROM DUAL;
RETURN (retval);
END;
```

Than I used in the query:

```
select sum(NVL(ASK_SIZE,0))    as ASK_VOLUME, 

ifZeroReturnOne (sum(CASE WHEN NVL(ASK_SIZE,0)=0 THEN CASE WHEN BASE_CURR_ASK_PRICE=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ELSE ASK_SIZE END)    as ASK_PRICE,


EXCHANGE_SK         as EXCHANGE_SK, 
etc...............
```

Let me know if you have better suggestions